# How do I create a function such that a method can be called directly on the function return value?

Tags: javascript

I am using Selenium and need a small helper function that will allow a method to be called like so

```
await driver.findElement(By.className(test.buttonGenderClass)).click();
```

My helper function is like this:

```
async function GetButtonByTitle(title, driver){
  let text = "//button[text()='"+title+"']";
  return await driver.findElement(By.xpath(text));
}
```

Which works fine but has to be used like this:

```
let button = await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver);
button.click();
```

I would prefer if I could simply use it like this:

```
await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver).click();
```

What is required to create the GetButtonByTitle function such that it can be used like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up the `await` statement with parans:

```
(await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver)).click();
```

Alternatively, you can remove `async` from `GetButtonByTitle`.

```
function GetButtonByTitle(title, driver){
  let text = "//button[text()='"+title+"']";
  return await driver.findElement(By.xpath(text));
}
......

await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver).click();
```

It's essentially an order of operations problem.

Comment: Ok I will try that - why is that not required with the selenium findElement() method?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald `GetButtonByTitle()` returns a `Promise`, which has no `.click()` method. Since property accessor has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence#table) than `await` (17 vs. 14), `await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver).click()` is parsed as `await (GetButtonByTitle("START", driver).click())`. On the other hand and by the same token, `await driver.findElement()` is already parsed as `await (driver.findElement())` so there is no need for explicit parentheses.

Comment: OK so back to my original question - how would I write the GetButtonByTitle() method so that it gets parsed in the same way findElement() does ?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Make the function `GetButtonByTitle` not `async`. Then `await GetButtonByTitle("START", driver).click();` will work. It's an order of operations problem.

Comment: What !  you can await a non async function in js ??!!

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald You're awaiting the `click` at that point due to order of operations as `GetButtonByTitle` no longer is awaited itself. You're still awaiting the the first function that needs to be awaited in the chained functions being called.